# Mongoose 5 async connection trouble

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

According to [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#error-handling), the proper way for handling errors during initial connection is this:

```
try {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', { useNewUrlParser: true });
} catch (error) {
  handleError(error);
}
```

Unfortunately, this results in a SyntaxError:

```
await mongoose.connect(mongoConnectionString, { useNewUrlParser: true });
       ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

When I remove `await`, the code is executed without any issues. When I googled `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier with await`, I found that this happens when `await` is used with a not async function. But this doesn't make any sense since Mongoose is using asnyc connect from version 5 on. Also, the following async code is working properly as well:

```
mongoose.connect(mongoConnectionString, {
       useNewUrlParser: true
     })
       .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
       .catch(err => console.log(err));
   });
```

The dependency in `package.json`:
`"mongoose": "^5.6.0`"

`index.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoConnectionString = `mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_DB_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_DB_PW}@mongodb4711:27017/visitor-ips`;

initialMongoConnect(mongoose, mongoConnectionString);

function initialMongoConnect(mongoose, mongoConnectionString) { 
   try {
     await mongoose.connect(mongoConnectionString, { useNewUrlParser: true });

   } catch (error) {
     handleError(error, mongoose, mongoConnectionString);
   }
  console.log('Initial connect to MongoDB successful');
}

function handleError(error, mongoose, mongoConnectionString) {
   console.log('Error on initial connection: ' + error);
   // wait 3 seconds and try to do the initial connect again
   setTimeout(function() {initialMongoConnect(mongoose, mongoConnectionString)}, 3000);
}
```

So what's the issue with `await` here?

Answer (score -1):

mongoose async operations, it supports promise  runs async by default it doesn't  need to await function because it is async  when its success used then (()=>"what should do when it connection ) if it error use catch(()=>"what happened when the error happened ) and you should  use keyword to used await that is async in start the function that wants to run as async function example 
const a=async function(){
await  ///what it is  await the need  to domming

Comment: Well, using await for the initial mongoose.connect is one of the suggested ways of proper error handling according to the official mongoosejs.com/docs, so I wouldn't want to argue whether it is needed or not. This doesn't answer the question why await doesn't work.

Comment: @Hans `await` doesn't work because you're using it in a non-async function. You can't use `await` in a function that hasn't been declared as `async`. Using `then` and `catch| is equivalent to using `await` btw; they're just two different syntax for doing the same thing.

Comment: @Paulpro thanks for your comment. I don't understand how it can be proposed to use await on the official mongoose ressources if it is a non-async function. Are you sure about that? await and then/catch can be equivalent but not if you really want to halt and not let your other code be executed while until the Promise is returned. In the case of a initial connection it can make sense to really halt and not move on with anything else.

Comment: @Hans Whether you want to halt or not doesn't change the fact that `await` and `then` do the same thing. Neither of them halt/block the event loop.

Comment: @Hans The docs are just not showing the context. That code with `await` works perfectly well, but it must be inside an `async` function. `await` is a syntax error anywhere else until future versions of EcmaScript once https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await gets through. Then it will still be a syntax error inside non-async functions but will be allowed in modules outside of all functions.